# unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Just learning how to work with php and mysql, using CodeIgniter. Running into that error.

I am attempted to check login attempts against my database, where they are stored. Here are the related functions in my login model:

```
public function verify_user($email, $password)
    {
        $q = $this
        ->db
        ->where('email_address', $email)
        ->where('password', $password)
        ->limit(1)
        ->get('users');

            if ($q->num_rows > 0)
                return $q->row();
            }
            add_login_attempt($email);
            return false;
        }

        public function add_login_attempt($email)
        {
            $current_attempts = get_login_attempts($email);

            if ($current_attempts > 2)
            {
                lock_account($email);
            }
            else
            {
                $updated_attempts = $current_attempts + 1;
                $data = array('login_attempts' => $updated_attempts);
                $this->db->where('email_address', $email);
                $this->db->update('crm', $data);
            }

        }

        function reset_login_attempts($email)
        {

        }

        function lock_account($email)
        {

        }

        public function get_login_attempts($email)
        {
            $this->db->select('login_attempts');
            $this->db->from('crm');
            $this->db->where('email_address', $email);
            $login_attempts = $this->db->get();

            return $login_attempts;
        }
}
```

Logging in using correct credentials works no problem. When an incorrect password is entered, that error is encountered. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a syntax error :

```
if ($q->num_rows > 0)
    return $q->row();
}
```

Should be:

```
if ($q->num_rows > 0) {
    return $q->row();
}
```

You forgot the `{`